My WooCommerce email template is not in the list of emails. Where do I find it?
I am working on a WooCommerce shop and I am using manual bank transfer as payment method until there is another payment method to add. It all works fine, and the customer receives an email after checkout, stating that the order will be processed after payment.
I want to edit that email, but when I go to: WooCommerce->Settings->Emails, I can't find this specific template. They all have other text. The text is German (Vielen Dank für Ihre Bestellung. Die Bearbeitung erfolgt nach Zahlungseingang.). It is also not in the template files, they are all in English. I have checked if there were settings if I edit the payment option, but the text also doesn't match.
I have absolutely no idea, where this text comes from. If I google the problem, there is only one response, to check the email settings in WooCommerce, but none of the templates match the one that WooCommerce is using. Can anybody help me find it? I am using just WooCommerce without any plugins yet.

Try to use Loco Translate plugin, that allow to translate or edit translations, as the original English texts are translated via .po and .mo translation files located in wp-content/languages.

That was it. I have found the translation there in that folder. I will check the plugin. Thank you very much! :-)
